# Charmed-Kubernates

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, nginx

I have installed Charmed-Kubernates with snap rolling the following instructions....https://ubuntu.com/blog/kubernetes-on-a-single-machine
I all started up apart from nginx I asked it to use the bridge I had created however I am not sure it did as the ip addressing of the cluster is not representative of the IP on the bridge, however that maybe me not understanding as the system may use internal addressing not my ip subnet - if so how do I overcome or begin to find out how to overcome the nginx failed install ?
image below

[JUJU STATUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkMvm.jpg)

Comment: Your question is very confusing please read it and consider re wording it.

Comment: I'm sorry it all came up apart from nginx which failed, I put it off for the moment, but would like to revisit the thing when I have time. 
I believe that the issue arose because the br0 I gave to juju wasn't used and so possibly this led to issues with nigh load balancer not being able to install.

I have moved on and set up a smaller  MicroK8s server because I need to install this solution
https://itnext.io/using-httpd-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-openid-connect-authentication-791d7e517608

Comment: I got so far but stumbled on this old bit of code....
I changed the top line to 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

$ cat > keycloak-ingress.yaml << EOF
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - sso.example.net
      secretName: tls-sso
  rules:
  - host: "sso.example.net"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
EOF
I realise that the top line is wrong and assume much else is also -

Comment: This comes back with various errors due to i assume the imcompatibility of the versions used. I have seen outlines of how to translate from the beta version to v1 but nothing works